# Switch on Change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

Append The Switch

```
$('#ehdr').append('<span id="mySelect2"><select name="switch" id="goingswitch" data-role="slider" data-mini="true"><option value="notgoing"></option><option value="going">Going</option></select></span>');
```

JS

```
$('#goingswitch').change( function() {

alert("works");

});
```

This is not alerting when I switch

Comment: From my end, this works on chrome, firefox, safari and the nasty IE, given that you set the event on an already existing `#goingswitch`

Comment: what do you mean by already existing?

Comment: Try this fiddle to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/mjLLW/1/

Comment: but the difference between mine and yours is the append function, that probably is screwing up something

Comment: look my answer and rethink.

Comment: is there possibly a problem in the fact that my switch button is in the header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to use event delegation model of event registration using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) because I assume the event registration is happening before the element is added to the dom

```
$('#ehdr').on('change', '#goingswitch', function() {
    alert("works");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z8V4N/)

Comment: +1 I was about to post this exact same answer, you got the point.

Comment: +1. Great Arun! I did not test `event registration is happening before the element is added to the dom` with my provided answer.

Answer (score 2):

instead use following, [see demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/zainshaikh/2y8YN/1/)

```
$('#goingswitch').on('change', function() {

    alert("works");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `delegate` or `on`

```
$('body').delegate('#goingswitch','change', function() {

alert("works");

});

//for on see Arun P johny's answer
```

Answer (score -1):

> Your code also works fine for me . [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fKqQX/)

```
<>
```